# Maven Integration tests and unit tests with profile

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I wonder why it is not working corecttly. I want to have itTest profle which will start integration(failsafe plugin) and unit(surefire plugin) via Maven.
My configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${unit-tests.skip}</skip>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${integration-tests.skip}</skip>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

profile

```
<profile>
        <id>itTest</id>
        <properties>
            <propFile>profiles/itTest.properties</propFile>
            <spring.profile>itTest</spring.profile>
            <integration-tests.skip>false</integration-tests.skip>
            <unit-tests.skip>false</unit-tests.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Result: both tests are skipped... even i change profile or hardcoded skip to false it still doesnt work.

Comment: First the exclude in maven-surefire-plugin is simply redundant, cause it's default in maven-surefire-plugin. The include in maven-failsafe-plugin is also redundant, cause it's the default in maven-failsave-plugin...

Comment: Have you actually activated the profile with `mvn -P itTest`?

Comment: yes, i do it via Intellij interface where i declare profile and command where command is verify but if i change true for it and unit test also might be another command like install

Comment: What happens if you remove both the `excludes` and `includes` blocks?

Comment: Nothing change, but i found interesting thing. When i run ``clean install`` with hardcoded values like false/true tests are runinng or not but when it comes to run with any profile than they are skipped

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting both plugins in as default and trying to skip them I think you can simply declare the plugins within the profiles themselves.
I.e.

```
<profile>
    <id>itTest</id>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    <plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly your configuration does not do what you want it to do (probably something about the order in which properties are evaluated, so the property is already evaluated when you reset it), but the usual way to handle this is to put the whole plugin configuration into the profile.

Comment: yes, it could be solution but id doesnt satisfy me, i would like have global plugin where other profile can use it( so i declare variables to manage surefire and failsafe)

Comment: Can you elaborate more in detail what you think of and how it should look like?

Comment: Ok, i try. Assume that i have 3 profiles with these variable(unit-test.skip,integration-test.skip) and now only itTest will be running both tests but in the future i would like to be fexible and if i want to run unit test with my 1 profile all what i need is only change variable from false to true in this particular profile. This is why i dont want to pull it into itTest profile.